# Identifying a specific thread's entry in dm_exec_requests

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading

I have a set of worker processes (System.Threading.Thread) that are executing 
queries on a MSSQL Server. In certain situations, (i.e. bugs that will be fixed in the long-term) a query takes a long time to execute, and I've been asked to provide a way for admin-users (of this application, not DB admins) to find and kill that query *from the application*.

I found [this post with a SQL query I can use to get a list of open SQL commands](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/) in my DBMS, but I cant seem to find any data in the resultset that uniquely identifies one specific thread's hung SqlCommand/Transaction/Connection

Background info: To investigate this possible solution using Visual Studio 2013 and SSMS, I created a class (in VS, .net 4.5) that wraps a pair of threads, "worker" and "watcher". Worker opens a transaction, and assigns a reference to it on its' wrapper class (so I can do some poking around at a breakpoint from the perspective of the "watcher" thread). Then, it runs a "simulate long-running query" command, a WAITFOR... Meanwhile, Watcher sleeps until the worker is waiting for the long-running query to complete, then hits a breakpoint. At this point, I switch to SSMS and run a modified version of the query from the link above:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext WHERE wait_type = 'WAITFOR'
```

Then I return to VS and dig into the locals (which include instance-local references to the SqlTransaction, SqlConnection and SqlCommand created by "Worker") to try to find any field with a value that matches one of the columns in the SELECT query's resultset...

Here's an example of the type of class that will be running these queries. (Ignore any nitpicky details about connection/transaction etc - rest assured I have my connection open and all that basic stuff is fuctioning)

```
public class WorkerThreadTest {
    private SqlTransaction workerTransaction;
    private SqlConnection workerConnection;
    private SqlCommand workerCommand;

    private System.Threading.Thread worker;
    private System.Threading.Thread watcher;

    WorkerThreadTest() {
        worker = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Run));
        watcher = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Watch));
        worker.Start();
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private void Run() {
        // Paraphrasing here //
        workerTransaction = new Transaction(foo); 
        workerConnection = new SqlConnection(foo);

        // Again, paraphrasing:
        workerCommand = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '0:05';", workerConnection, workerTransaction);
        workerCommand.Execute(foo); // Thread will wait on this line for 5 minutes
        bool placeBreakPointHere = true;
    }

    private void Watch() {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(foo); // Wait enough time for worker to execute its command
        bool placeBreakPointHere = true;
        // Here is where I explore my locals
    }
}


// Inside main program:
WorkerThreadTest myWorkerThread = new WorkerThreadTest();
```

And here is a sample row returned from the SQL query after the worker thread has executed the WAITFOR:

```
session_id  request_id  start_time  status  command sql_handle  statement_start_offset  statement_end_offset    plan_handle database_id user_id connection_id   blocking_session_id wait_type   wait_time   last_wait_type  wait_resource   open_transaction_count  open_resultset_count    transaction_id  context_info    percent_complete    estimated_completion_time   cpu_time    total_elapsed_time  scheduler_id    task_address    reads   writes  logical_reads   text_size   language    date_format date_first  quoted_identifier   arithabort  ansi_null_dflt_on   ansi_defaults   ansi_warnings   ansi_padding    ansi_nulls  concat_null_yields_null transaction_isolation_level lock_timeout    deadlock_priority   row_count   prev_error  nest_level  granted_query_memory    executing_managed_code  group_id    query_hash  query_plan_hash statement_sql_handle    statement_context_id    dbid    objectid    number  encrypted   text
112 2   2015-03-24 16:34:12.433 suspended   WAITFOR 0x01004300C7A0DC2CB05D23780200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  118 -1  0x06004300C7A0DC2CF07EA34A0400000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  67  1   9E1EF06D-A755-4EBD-82AA-B030F8B6D19B    0   WAITFOR 72294   WAITFOR     1   1   433172712   0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  0   0   0   72294   4   0x0000000243685468  0   0   0   -1  us_english  mdy 7   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   -1  0   0   0   2   0   0   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    67  NULL    NULL    0   (@ContextInfo varbinary(10))SET CONTEXT_INFO @ContextInfo WAITFOR DELAY '0:05';
```

**Is there any way I can uniquely identify the row that matches a specific instance of my worker thread?**

(NOTE: There is no guarantee the hostname, ip, or query-text will be unique)

Comment: Also, I'm not partial to dm_exec_requests, any means of identifying the session_id, or any other means of killing the query DBMS-side, would do.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this.

In the application I would show a list of all queries, similar to SSMS. That list can be obtained from [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) as you already know. Actually, I would show not all queries, but those that have been running longer than some threshold (use `start_time`), i.e. those that maybe should be stopped.

Application would have a command to [`kill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173730.aspx) any query by its Session ID.

I don't see a need to find particular thread in the rest of the application that is running a query that should be killed. As soon as the query is killed, the thread's `Execute` most likely would throw some exception. Catch and process it accordingly. The long-running query could have been started by another instance of the application on another client computer, so any information about the client thread is useless.

So, the end user sees a list of all queries on the server that have been running for a long time, can see for how long they have been running so far and can kill any such query.

Why this approach doesn't suit you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - The reason this solution doesn't work is that we can't put a definition on "too long" - In some case, a report may be _expected_ to take a very long time (we'll be dealing with "big data", along with year-end processes). Thus, the decision to kill a report must be left to the user. Also, there are multiple security profiles in play so one user may not be able to see a query run by another user or group. So, we need to show a user a list that only includes the threads that can be modified by him/her in particular, then allow him/her to cancel one at their discretion.

Comment: So, it means that you need to filter the output of `sys.dm_exec_requests` somehow. Still, you don't need to identify particular threads. You just need to figure out which queries the user has rights to kill. You can start with looking at `HostName` and `Login` and show to the user only those queries that originated from his computer and under his login. Still, the main idea is that you kill the query, not the thread, the thread will die by itself when the query is killed.

Comment: Also, you already know that you can retrieve the text of the running query using `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`, so you can include something in the query text to help you figure out what you need, like the report name or the thread ID, or user ID. In a way that doesn't affect the query itself. I would try to add this info in a comment in the query text, or extra `PRINT` statement, or extra parameter to the stored procedure and check if it is visible through `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`.

Comment: Yeah, the last one is the route I decided to take - I encode uniquely identifying information in a comment inside the thread, and used that unique ID in a LIKE %id% filter to isolate the query in question. Thanks!